# get an accurate time with NTP, GPS and PPS as soon as possible

Tags: ntp

Because I work with an astronomic application I need an accurate UTC time.
Now I use NTP with GPS with 1PPS over RS232 as refclock.

```
server 127.127.20.0 mode 18 minpoll 4 maxpoll 4 prefer
fudge 127.127.20.0 flag1 1 flag2 0 flag3 1 flag4 0 time2 0.475
```

I read that NTP is syncing the time by in- or decreasing the speed of hardware clock e.g. to avoid duplicate times if a step would be to large.

Because the computer is turned off from time to time NTP needs some time to get in sync. It depends how far the system clock was drifted away. If I'm wrong please correct me.

Is there a possibility to force the almost instant use of a prefered GPS time? Getting time sync even faster as usual would be also sufficient.

Actually, in an astronomic environment it's more important to have an accurate time asap than having a nice time shift algorithm which could be kind of slow.

Answer (score 0):

When starting ntpd, the ntp deamon, there is an option q ( -q ) to cause ntp to immediately reset the time. The command "man ntpd" describes it and also the g option which you might want to use.

Most people prefer to do a quick time reset only on startup, by using the q option of ntpd (or the old way of doing it, ntpdate). Once the clock is set, you can use the standard startup command.

On many Linux systems, ntpd will be started at boot time, in which case the time will already be correct within 128 ms. If the computer is suspended or hibernated, the error could be greater though. A manual procedure to increase the accuracy would be:

```
sudo service ntp stop
sudo ntpd -q
sudo ntpd start
```